# Qual o melhor Tipo Mysql para armazenar valores numéricos

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela onde armazena a quantidade de vagas em valores numéricos. Gostaria de saber qual o melhor tipo mysql para armazenar esses valores, levando em consideração que ele poderá ser calculado com outro campo que receberá o mesmo tipo de uma outra tabela.

Comment: Depende do tamanho dos números que você quer armazenar. O meio-termo é `INT`. que aceita o valor máximo 2147483648 e mínimo -2147483648.

Comment: Show de bola bfavaretto. Então não teria problemas em calcular 02 campos que armazenam valores numéricos certo? Por ex (02 variáveis em PHP com valores vindos do BD).: `$campo1 - $campo2`.

Comment: Não. Mas com os dados que tem na outra pergunta não dá pra dizer com segurança que é problema de tipagem. O PHP deveria converter corretamente na hora da subtração. Tem algo estranho no conjunto da sua aplicação que não sabemos o que é.

Answer (score 1):

> quantidade de vagas em valores numéricos

Considerando que não haverá número negativo, o campo pode ser do tipo `int unsigned` que irá armazenar de 0 a 4294967295.

Se for um db imenso e for cogitar redução de espaço, pode utilizar outros tipos numéricos inteiros:

```
CREATE TABLE `inttypes` (                       -- SIGNED ( -X ~ X )    UNSIGNED ( 0 ~ X )
    `tinyint` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL,          -- 127                  255
    `smallint` SMALLINT(6) DEFAULT NULL,        -- 32767                65535
    `mediumint` MEDIUMINT(9) DEFAULT NULL,      -- 8388607              16777215
    `int` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,                 -- 2147483647           4294967295
    `bigint` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL            -- 9223372036854775807  18446744073709551615
);
```

**Fonte:**
[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual - 11.2.1 Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)